# What is causing the difference in these two loops?

Tags: c#, increment

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int res = 1;
    while (res <= num)
    {
        res++;
        if ((res % 2) == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the int 8, 10, and 5 as my control groups, these SHOULD just output the even numbers starting at 1 and going till the input number(8,10,5).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int res = 1; res <= num; res++)
    {
        if ((res % 2) == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me understand?

Comment: What is the difference that you're seeing?

Comment: @Enigmativity mainly it is with the odd counts, the while loop gives me the number 6, when it should stop at 4.

Comment: You should have included that detail in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in the second loop, you are incrementing `res` at the very end of each iteration (that's how a for loop works), whereas in the first loop, you increment `res` before you check for "even".

This means that when `res` is 5 and a new iteration of the while loop starts, `res` gets incremented to 6 first, and 6 passes the check, causing 6 to be printed. In the for loop however, `res` is incremented after 5 not passing the even check. The iteration then stops since 6 is now greater than 5.

To make the while loop the same as the for loop, move `res++` to the end:

```
while (res <= num)
{
    if ((res % 2) == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
    res++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that detailed explanation, could you explain how to make the while loop output the same as the for loop?

Comment: Oh wow... I really need a better understanding of code structure.

Answer (score 2):

In the first loop you increase the variable `res` before check if it is even.

In the second loop you check if it is event and in the end of each iteration you increase the value of `res` variable.